# How To Convert Tangent Space Normal Map to World Space?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, normals

I'm trying to convert my [tangent space normal map](https://i.imgur.com/fURjYnD.jpg) to world space. Why, you might ask? Because my tangent space normal map produces seams when placed next to an adjacent mesh with a continuation of the texture. I'm not sure if converting from tangent to world would work, but I have to try.

I know that to compute the TBN matrix, you need three vectors: the tangent, bitangent, and normal, as stated in [OpenGL Tutorial 13 : Normal Mapping](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/)

The library I'm using is Three.js, which has a method that computes the tangent for you. It is already [defined here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L472) and sets it as an attribute to be passed to the shader. This makes my life a lot easier. I can then compute the TBN matrix like this:

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 tangent;
uniform sampler2D tx;
varying vec3 vn;
varying vec3 vp;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec4 vt;

void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  vp = position;
  vn = normal;
  vt = tangent;
  vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  gl_Position  = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
varying vec3 vn;
varying vec3 vp;
varying vec4 vt;
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform sampler2D tx;


float light(vec3 normalMap, vec3 lightPosition, vec3 cP) {

    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosition - normalMap.xyz);
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(cP - normalMap.xyz);
    vec3 ambientColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);  // Ambient light color
    vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);  // Diffuse light color
    vec3 specularColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2); // Specular light color
    float shininess = 0.0;  // Material shininess factor

    // Ambient lighting calculation
    vec3 ambient = ambientColor;

    // Diffuse lighting calculation
    float diffuseIntensity = max(dot(normalMap.xyz, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity;

    // Specular lighting calculation
    vec3 reflectionDirection = reflect(-lightDirection, normalMap.xyz);
    float specularIntensity = pow(max(dot(reflectionDirection, viewDirection), 0.0), shininess);
    vec3 specular = specularColor * specularIntensity;

    // Final lighting calculation
    vec3 finalColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    return clamp(dot(normalMap.xyz, lightDirection), 0.0, 1.0) * max(max(finalColor.r, finalColor.g), finalColor.b);
}





void main() {
vec3 nMap = texture2D(tx,vUv).rgb;

vec4 tangent = vt;
vec3 bitangent = normalize(cross(tangent.rgb,vn));
mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent.rgb,bitangent,normalize(vn));

vec3 worldSpaceNormal = normalize(TBN * nMap);

//uncomment it add light
/*
vec3 lightDirection = vec3(0.,0.,100.);
vec3 cameraPosition = vec3(0.,0.,0.);
float finalColor = light(worldSpaceNormal,lightDirection,cameraPosition);
*/
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(worldSpaceNormal), 1.0);

}
```

The results are not as expected. If this were correct, it should look more like this image. This is the normal I'm trying to produce.

[image]

```js
let camera,scene,mesh,renderer


//----- get the src and set to texture----
const nmap  = document.getElementById('nmap' ).src;
const texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(nmap);

// Create a custom shader material
const vertexShader = `
attribute vec4 tangent;
uniform sampler2D tx;
varying vec3 vn;
varying vec3 vp;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec4 vt;

vec3 orthogonal(vec3 n){
 return normalize(
 abs(n.x)>abs(n.z) ? vec3(-n.y,n.x,0.) : vec3(0.,-n.z,n.y)
 );
}


void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  vp = position;
  vn = normal;
  vt = tangent;
  vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  gl_Position  = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`;




const fragmentShader = `
varying vec3 vn;
varying vec3 vp;
varying vec4 vt;
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform sampler2D tx;


float light(vec3 normalMap, vec3 lightPosition, vec3 cP) {

    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosition - normalMap.xyz);
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(cP - normalMap.xyz);
    vec3 ambientColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);  // Ambient light color
    vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);  // Diffuse light color
    vec3 specularColor = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2); // Specular light color
    float shininess = 0.0;  // Material shininess factor

    // Ambient lighting calculation
    vec3 ambient = ambientColor;

    // Diffuse lighting calculation
    float diffuseIntensity = max(dot(normalMap.xyz, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity;

    // Specular lighting calculation
    vec3 reflectionDirection = reflect(-lightDirection, normalMap.xyz);
    float specularIntensity = pow(max(dot(reflectionDirection, viewDirection), 0.0), shininess);
    vec3 specular = specularColor * specularIntensity;

    // Final lighting calculation
    vec3 finalColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    return clamp(dot(normalMap.xyz, lightDirection), 0.0, 1.0) * max(max(finalColor.r, finalColor.g), finalColor.b);
}





void main() {
vec3 nMap = texture2D(tx,vUv).rgb;

vec4 tangent = vt;
vec3 bitangent = normalize(cross(tangent.rgb,vn));
mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent.rgb,bitangent,normalize(vn));

vec3 worldSpaceNormal = normalize(TBN * nMap);

//uncomment it add light
/*
vec3 lightDirection = vec3(0.,0.,100.);
vec3 cameraPosition = vec3(0.,0.,0.);
float finalColor = light(worldSpaceNormal,lightDirection,cameraPosition);
*/
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(worldSpaceNormal), 1.0);

}
`;


// animation
init()


function init(){
//-----------Basic setUp
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.setClearColor( 'white' )

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 20;
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
scene = new THREE.Scene();

//------------front
let frontUnifrom = {tx:{value:texture1}}
let front = createPlaneMesh(0,0,0,0,0,0,frontUnifrom)
scene.add( front );

}


//--------build mesh
function createPlaneMesh(x, y, z, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ, uniforms) {
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 50, 50);
planeGeometry.computeTangents()
const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
});
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
planeMesh.position.set(x, y, z);
planeMesh.rotation.set(rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ);
planeMesh.frustumCulled = false
return planeMesh;
}

//-----------
function animation( time ) {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/build/three.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
<img id='nmap' src="https://i.imgur.com/fURjYnD.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
```